# Marketing Cloud Content Builder - How to show dynamic Graph

Tags: marketing-cloud

How do I show graph using TriggeredSendDefinition ? First of all how do I even define a template for graphs. I have done some basic templates but not graphs.

Comment: Welcome to the SFSE community! Please can you clarify what you are trying to achieve here and edit your question expand on your use case? It's quite ambiguous and I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. Do you want to include a dynamic graph within a Triggered Send email?

Comment: @EliotHarper Yes. Dynamic graph within a Triggered send email.

Answer (score 1):

Marketing Cloud doesn't have a chart generation feature, but there are several image-based chart APIs available that you can use, for example [Image Charts](https://www.image-charts.com), [Chartworks](https://www.chartworks.io/charts/image) and others.

I'm using Google's [image chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) which is now deprecated, but Google state that they have no plans to turn it off and there's no limit to the number of calls per day. It's free, easy to use and doesn't require authentication, but if you are looking at a long-term solution and receive support, then you may want to review alternative APIs.

### HTML Email

I'm using the following HTML in my email and have created a Triggered Send that uses this email.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

%%[
var @chartDataStringS1, @chartDataStringS2, @chartDataStringS3, @chartDataStringS4, @params, @xAxis, @width, @height

set @chartDataStringS1 = AttributeValue('chartDataStringS1')
set @chartDataStringS2 = AttributeValue('chartDataStringS2')
set @chartDataStringS3 = AttributeValue('chartDataStringS3')
set @chartDataStringS4 = AttributeValue('chartDataStringS4')
set @xAxis = '2010|2011|2012|2013|2014|2015|2016|2017'
set @width = 500
set @height = 250
set @line1Label = 'Ponies'
set @line2Label = 'Unicorns'

set @params = Concat('cht=lxy&chd=t:', @chartDataStringS1, '|', @chartDataStringS2, '|',  @chartDataStringS3, '|', @chartDataStringS4, '&chl=', @xAxis, '&chs=', @width, 'x', @height, '&chco=FF0000,0000FF&chdl=', @line1Label, '|', @line2Label, '&chxt=x,y')
]%%

<h2>Pony Versus Unicorn Distribution</h2>

<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?%%=v(@params)=%%" />

</body>
</html>
```

### REST API Method

The following method is used to send the Triggered Send email using the REST API. Note that `{{key}}` is the External Key of the Triggered Send and `{{accessToken}}` is the OAuth access token from the [Authentication Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm).

```js
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{{key}}/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}

{
    "To": {
        "Address": "someone@company.com",
        "Name": "Eliot Harper",
        "SubscriberKey": "0037F00000EwYYc",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "chartDataStringS1":"10,20,40,80,85,90,95",
                "chartDataStringS2":"20,30,40,50,60,70,85",
                "chartDataStringS3":"-10",
                "chartDataStringS4":"5,10,25,45,65,70,75"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

The following email is sent to the Subscriber.

[image: image chart]